# Cardinality of $L$, $L = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \mid x + y = 5\}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Like the title says,

$L = \{(x,y) \in  \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \mid x + y = 5\}$

I need to find the cardinality of L, I have an idea of an answer, but I don't know what function I need to build, because the $x+y = 5$, which ruins everything (for me).

I know that in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, I could have infinity (duh) $x +y = 5$, like: $(0.1,4.9)$, $(0.01,4.99)$, $(0.001,4.999)$, etc...

But I can't find a proper function to show whether it's $\aleph_{0} $ or $c$

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This set describes a line.  The mapping $x \mapsto (x,5-x)$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{R} \to L$, so L has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$.  In other words, $|L|=\mathcal{c}$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, could you possibly explain deeper how you approached this problem ?

Comment: If you plot $L$, you get a line.  So intuitively, $L$ has the same number of points as the real axis.  So we construct a bijection from the real line to $L$.